# How to request an enhancement to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to request some enhancements be made to PostgreSQL.

For example, request that PostgreSQL implement the direct equivalent of Oracle's KEEP clause functionality:

- `max(city) keep (dense_rank first order by population desc)`
- [PostgreSQL equivalent to Oracle's MAX(...) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST/LAST ORDER BY ...)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/324426/postgresql-equivalent-to-oracles-max-keep-dense-rank-first-last-order-by)

I tried googling "PostgreSQL ideas" and "PostgreSQL request enhancement". But I don't see any sort of portal for submitting requests for new functionality.

---

Is there a website I can use to request enhancements to PostgreSQL?

Comment: Post to the mailing list https://www.postgresql.org/list/  ("General" is a good place to start)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks! I registered and sent an email to the *General* mailing list, as you suggested. The email was titled: *"Idea: PostgreSQL equivalent to Oracle's KEEP clause"*. I don't think I've ever used a mailing list before. Hopefully I did it right.

Comment: In this particular case, your request will burn down to requesting to add the existing `first()` and `last()` aggregate functions into the main release. (I am all for it!) See answer to your linked question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/324646/3684